# $\text{ Proving }\; A \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ A is bounded above} \Rightarrow A^c \text{ is not?} $

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

> Prove: Let $A \subseteq \Bbb R$. Prove that if $A$ is bounded above, then $A^c$, the complement of $A$ is not bounded above.

$ A^c = $ those element of the universe that are not in A.

$ \Bbb R =$ real numbers.

Proof: (direct proof)

Suppose that $A^c$ is bounded above and $ s= \text{supremum}(A), t = \text{supremum}(A^c)  $

$\Rightarrow$ $a\le s, ∀ a \in A; b \le t,  ∀ b \in B.$ .

How does one finish this proof? Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded above there is a real number $M$ so that if $x>M$ then $x \in A^{c}$.

Therefore no $N$ exists so that if $x>N$ then $ x\not\in N$ ( since $\max(N+1,M+1)\in A^c$). So $A^c$ is not bounded above.

Comment: What is $M'$? I did not read that in the problem.

Comment: a set $A$ is bounded if there exists a real number $M$ so that if $x>M$ then $x\not\in A$. What we prove is that we cannot find a suitable $M'$ for the set $A^c$.

Comment: I just do not know what the apostrophe signifies in $M'$. It seems important.

Comment: It is an entirely different variable, I'll change it for an $N$.